# How should I setup my jsp folder in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, servlet-3.0

I have downloaded a spring project in spring.io. However, I cannot find webapp folder. However, there are static and templates folders. Can someone teach me how to create WebMvcConfigurer and Servelet programmatically and run it using tomcat? Thank you.

Comment: So did you get this squared away?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a very good question.

SHORT ANSWER:

`src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp`

LONGER ANSWER:

I recently spent some time trying to get Spring Boot working with JSP, and found that I had to adjust several things:

1. build.gradle (or equivalently, pom.xml):

   ```
   dependencies {
      compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
      compile('javax.servlet:jstl')
      compile('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api')
      compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
      // compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')  // DISABLE THYMELEAF
      compile('org.webjars:bootstrap:4.1.0')
   ...
   ```
2. Update the main class and application.properties for .jsp

   Test7Application.java (main class):

   ```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Test7Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
       ... 
       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
           return application.sources(Test7Application.class);
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Test7Application.class, args);
       }
       ...
   ```

   application.properties:

   ```
    # Look here for jsp URLs:
    spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
   ```
3. Assign controllers routes as needed.

My complete notes are here:

https://github.com/paulsm4/HelloSpringBoot/tree/master/test7

I hope that helps...